# How to add multiple custom views on an activity on a button click?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-framelayout

I am making an app in which an image is loaded from the gallery, now the user can add re-sizable and dragable rectangles on the image on the click of a button. 
Right now i am able to add the image and also add a required rectangle on the image on the click of a button. 
But what i want is that if the button is clicked again, a new rectangle is added, and the previous is restored as it is.
My code is as below..

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity {

FrameLayout fm;   //framelayout to add views on the image

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();                      //5 lines
    final String value = bundle.getString("key");                 //of code
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(value);                 //to add
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView); //the image
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);                                //from gallery



    Button bd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDraw); //button to add rectangle
fm = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_view);    //framelayout object


        bd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                DrawPanel dview=new DrawPanel(ImageActivity.this); 
                fm.addView(dview); 

            }});

}
```

}

I am creating a new object of mycustom view for the rectangle each time the button is clicked. The problem here is that when the button is clicked for the first time, the rectangle is drawn with each of its functionalities.
But when i click the button again the previous one vanishes and no new rectangle is drawn.
There is no message in the console or in the log cat. What am i doing wrong...

Comment: dview is a frameLayout, and according to the SDK: FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view,  it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity 
Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top.

Comment: ok, so you mean i should change the gravity each time i create a new object of dview.. can you please tell me how to do this in my code?

Comment: yes, you'll want to use FrameLayout.LayoutParams to accomplish this. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html